# Save shipping address after setting it by jquery

Tags: magento2, checkout

After setting shipping address by jQuery:

```
$('input[name=city]').val('test city');
```

But after setting it and going to payment, city is not saved.
Tried triggering keyup on this field but it is not working.

How can i save city after setting it with jQuery?

Answer (score -1):

Hope it helps someone still looking for answer
You need to trigger change event, I have done something similar to have default shipping address added in specific condition.

The custom address has to be passed to quote and change event does that by itself.

Below code will add custom city when clicked on element with class addCustomCity

cityVal should be city name to be added in shipping address.

You can modify it as per your requirements.

```
 require([
        'jquery',
        'uiRegistry'
    ],
    function($,uiRegistry) {
        "use strict";
        $(document).ready(function () {
    
            $('.addCustomCity').on('click', function(event) {
                    var cityVal = "cityname";
                    let city = uiRegistry.get('checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.city').uid;
                    let domCity = $('#'+city);
                    if (domCity) {
                        domCity.val(cityVal);
                        domCity.trigger('change');
                    }
            });
            
        });
    });
```